# How to convert component with many states to react functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am new to react and I am stuck because of so many states that need to be converted to hooks and some must be updated please help.
I need to use react functions to work with react-redux.

```js
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);


class BigCalendar extends Component {

    state = {
        events: [{
            id: 2,
            title: 'DS STARTS',
            start: new Date(2016, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0),
            end: new Date(2016, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0),
        }],


    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        const now = new Date();
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        current().then((data)=>{

        });

        listEvents().then((data) => {


             const events=data;
             this.state = {
                 name: 'React',
                 events,
                 messages: messages,

             };

             this.setState({
                 events:[
                     ...this.state.events,
                     data
                 ]
             })
        });
    }
    handleSelect = ({start, end}) => {
        const title = window.prompt('New Event name');
        if (title) {
            this.setState({
                events: [
                    ...this.state.events,
                    {
                        start,
                        end,
                        title,
                        id: this.id,
                    },
                ],
            });
            createEvent({id: "some id", title: title, start: start, end: end});
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    A test for the React Big Calendar.
                </p>
                <div style={{height: '500pt'}}>
                    <Calendar
                        events={this.state.events}
                        startAccessor="start"
                        endAccessor="end"
                        selectable
                        onSelectSlot={this.handleSelect}
                        defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
                        localizer={localizer}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default BigCalendar;
```

I got a state that needs to be updated after click in bigCalendar.
I read so many articles but I got overwhelmed of number os states to be updated

Comment: Why do you "need to use react functions to work with react-redux"?

Comment: Because of useSelector and useDisatch only work in react functions component... It is hard to me to understand react I am new

Comment: Are you simply asking how to convert a class-based component to a functional component?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have multiple pieces of data that need to be kept in state you can either use multiple `useState` hooks (one for each state value):

```
const [id, setId] = useState(2);
const [title, setTitle] = useState('DS STARTS');
// ...
```

Or you can use a single one, with an object value:

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState({
  id: 2,
  title: 'DS STARTS',
  // ...
```

Generally speaking it's better to do the former, because then when unrelated data changes you don't re-render unnecessarily.  But that only applies to unrelated data: if all the data are conceptually linked, then keeping them in the same object can make sense.

For instance, if you have `foo` and `bar`, with sub-component A depending on `foo` and sub-component B depending on `bar`, and `foo` changes, `bar` will get re-rendered (although only in the virtual DOM, assuming it returns the same JSX) ... *if* you use a single state object for both.  If they are separate states though updating one won't impact components dependent on the other.

(But again, none of that matters if both A and B depend on both `foo` and `bar`, ie. if the data is connected.)

Also, with object values you can do `foo.baz = 5` ... and forget that that *won't* trigger a re-render (you have to do `setFoo({...foo, baz: 5})`).  Non-objects don't have that issue.

Also personally I feel like using separate `useState` hooks is cleaner on a human level, because then it truly makes "state variables" feel more like regular variables, in a "one per conceptual piece of information" sense.

P.S. If you have a complex app, you have lots of state: there's no way to "solve" that.  But if your issue is with having to *pass around* lots of state values between your components, you should read up on context in React, as it's designed to solve that problem.